# Is it safe to use rel nofollow on my sites pointing to each other?

Tags: seo, nofollow

I have 6 websites, all from the same niche, I would like to add a top bar on the home page of all 6 sites, with everyone's domain names, so that each website points to one another on the top of these sites:

> Our site network: domain1 domain2 domain3 domain4 domain5 domain6;

If I use rel `nofollow` will it leave me safe?

I remember that years ago I did something like this without using `nofollow`, I saw the websites being harmed! I was practically interpreted as blackhat by having "a menu" that points to other sites of mine! A relevance fell a lot! Just `nofollow` is enough? Is there anything else I can do to make sure you do not get me wrong with search engines?

```php
<div align='center'>
<?php echo ("our others websites:"); ?>  
<a rel="nofollow" href='http://domain1.com' target='_blank'> domain1 </a> | 
<a rel="nofollow" href='http://domain2.com' target='_blank'> domain2 </a> |
<a rel="nofollow" href='http://domain3.com' target='_blank'> domain3 </a> | 
<a rel="nofollow" href='http://domain4.com' target='_blank'> domain4 </a> | 
<a rel="nofollow" href='http://domain5.com' target='_blank'> domain5 </a> | 
<a rel="nofollow" href='http://domain6.com' target='_blank'> domain6 </a> |   
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

search engine not consider no follow links so it's safe
but Balance your Inbound and Outbound Links